# Prevent wordpress from sending password in Plain Text

Tags: wordpress

On my wordpress site when a user registers it sends their password in Plaintext... How do I prevent it from doing this?

Comment: Best would be to just let them choose a password during registration, that way you don't even need to email passwords to your users. I don't think there's a built in way to do it, but this might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64611/how-to-let-user-set-password-on-registration

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this:

1. Use SSL. Using SSL will encrypt information being sent so it will not be visible to anybody with anybody intercepting your network.
2. Encrypt using javascript before sending. This will add a fake layer of security. Any hacker with any degree of intelligence can easily modify the content being served or sniff out your algorithm. You can give this a try http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/ Encrypt the password before form submission. Remember this can be easily compromised

In summary, use SSL for failsafe encryption

Comment: The whole site is using ssl but I don't know if the sending of mail is over ssl

Comment: mails is a different thing. Is wordpress sending user password over email?

Comment: Yes it is sending it over email

Comment: The password generated as a new user in the email notification?

Comment: http://www.morgadinho.org/2010/06/11/wordpress-mu-turn-off-sending-emails-to-new-users/